# Tab control cookie not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, cookies, tabs

I have an asp.net mvc partial which contains a jquery ui tab control, marked up like so:

```
<div id="admin_tabs" class="tabs_admin">
    <div id="admin_header">
        <ul> 
            <span class="admin_title">Administration</span>
            <li style="float:right; display:inline"><a href="#maint_tab">Maintenance</a></li>
            <li style="float:right; display:inline"><a href="#log_tab">Logs</a></li>
            <li style="float:right; display:inline"><a href="#groups_tab">Groups</a></li>
            <li style="float:right; display:inline"><a href="#users_tab">Users</a></li>
            <li style="float:right; display:inline"><a href="#app_settings_tab">Application Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="app_settings_tab" class="tab_admin">
    </div>
    <div id="users_tab" class="tab_admin">
    </div>
    <div id="groups_tab" class="tab_admin">
    </div>
    <div id="log_tab" class="tab_admin">
    </div>
    <div id="maint_tab" class="tab_admin">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#admin_tabs").tabs({ selected: 4 });
</script>
```

This works fine. But I would like the application to remember what tab was last open when the page is refreshed, so I changed my JavaScript to

```
$("#admin_tabs").tabs({selected: 4, cookie: {}});
```

This immediately causes a javascript error and the tabs stop working. According to the chrome console, the error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined` occuring on Line 7520 of jquery-ui.js. I have included the cookie plugin prior to including jquery ui, but to no effect. The code which is breaking is

```
_cookie: function() {
    var cookie = this.cookie ||
        ( this.cookie = this.options.cookie.name || "ui-tabs-" + getNextListId() );
    return $.cookie.apply( null, [ cookie ].concat( $.makeArray( arguments ) ) );
```

It appears to break because there is no cookie set when I first load the page. Any clues as to why that might be, or any other way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. For some reason, the cookie plugin wasn't being included correctly. I had it in an external script, but moving it into the body of the document fixed the problem.